# Getting of list of top 3 per 2 parameters

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get a table of the top 3 rated users per project type per company?

### Here is my schema:

```
contact                                           users
--------------------------                        ----------------
id                                                id        
Contact_Title                                     Name_Title
Contact_First                                     Name_First
Contact_Middle                                    Name_Middle
Contact_Last                                      Name_Last
Lead_Referral_Source                              Email
Date_of_Initial_Contact                           Password
Title                                             User_Roles
Company                                           User_Status
Industry
Address
Address_Street_1
Address_Street_2
Address_City
Address_State
Address_Zip
Address_Country
Phone
Email
Status
Website
LinkedIn_Profile
Background_Info
Sales_Rep
Rating
Project_Type
Project_Description
Proposal_Due_Date
Budget
Deliverables
```

I am just a beginner when it comes to SQL and am having a hard time with the logic. I haven't been able to make any progress with this question and would love to see how you guys might attempt it and hear some suggestions. Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: please add mock data(dml) and expected output. If you attach tables ddl it will be more convenient than just text

Comment: 1st question: Do the id's in each table correlate to each other? In other words, are user id 1 and contact id 1 the same person?  2nd question: What are the top three ratings (e.g. 1,2,3, etc.)?

Comment: @SeanW333 Oh sorry about that. So the contact's sales_rep is actually the thing that relates to the user's id

Comment: What about the ratings? Which are the best 3?

Comment: @SeanW333 So basically the ratings (Rating) are laid out from 1-10. The average has already been calculated and is being stored there. So I want the top 3 rated (Rating) Sales_Rep per Project_Type and Company. (aka. for a certain Project_Type within a certain company, who are the highest rated Sales_Reps?) I don't really understand how to get the top 3. I know I can use the max function to get the number 1. beyond that i'm pretty lost. So sorry for not describing my problem and table well.

Comment: So a single company/project_type combination will have multiple sales reps? And, the top three ratings could be any numbers between 1 and 10?

Comment: @SeanW333 yup yup yup

Comment: When you say "How can I get a table", do you really mean that you want to create a table and insert the data into the table, or do you really just want a query that shows you the data you want?

Comment: @SeanW333 I mainly just want a query that shows me the information I want. Things like (users full name, Email, Rating, Company, Project_Type)

Comment: Is a single sales rep every assigned to multiple contacts within one company/Project_type combination?

Comment: @SeanW333 A sales rep can only be assigned to a single contact company and project type. However there can be a single company/project type combination that can be assigned to several distinct sales reps.

Comment: I'm having a hard time coming up with any way to do this in MySQL using a single query. Would a stored procedure that creates and fills a table with the desired results be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @SeanW333 Yes I believe that could make for an acceptable solution. I to am having a very hard time coming up with a single query that can perform this action and am unsure what can be done. Thats a really good idea to create a stored procedure to create a table. I will also try moving in that direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it with a single query, but here is a stored procedure that will create a table in which to store the results, then populate that table with the results you need:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Get_Top_3_Rated_Salespeople_Per_Company_and_Project_Type;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS Get_Top_3_Rated_Salespeople_Per_Company_and_Project_Type()

    BEGIN

        DECLARE ct int;
        DECLARE comboCT int;
        DECLARE lt int;

        /* Create table where results will be stored */
        /* WARNING: Drops existing table first! */
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Top_3_Rated_Salespeople_Per_Company_and_Project_Type`;
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Top_3_Rated_Salespeople_Per_Company_and_Project_Type` (
            Name_First varchar(30),
            Name_Middle varchar(30),
            Name_Last varchar(100),
            Email varchar(100), 
            Rating numeric(6,4), 
            Company varchar(100), 
            Project_Type varchar(100)
        ); 


        /* Create temp table to store distinct Company/Project_Type combinations */
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_distinct_combos
            SELECT Project_Type, Company FROM contact GROUP BY Project_Type, Company;

        SET ct = 0;

        SET comboCT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_distinct_combos);

        /* For each combination in temp table, get top three ratings with associated user data
        /* and inset into Top_3_Rated_Salespeople_Per_Company_and_Project_Type */
        WHILE ct <= (comboCT + 1) DO

            SET lt = 1;

            INSERT INTO 
                `Top_3_Rated_Salespeople_Per_Company_and_Project_Type`

                SELECT
                    u.Name_First,
                    u.Name_Middle,
                    u.Name_Last,
                    u.Email,
                    c.Rating,
                    c.Company,
                    c.Project_Type
                FROM
                    contact as c 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    users AS u
                    ON 
                    u.id = c.Sales_Rep
                WHERE
                    /* Company/Project_Type combination matches current record in temp_distinct_combos */
                    CONCAT(c.Company, c.Project_Type) = (
                                                        SELECT
                                                            CONCAT(Company, Project_Type)
                                                        FROM
                                                            temp_distinct_combos
                                                        LIMIT
                                                            ct, lt /* this will limit this subquery to returning only one row at a time */
                                                        )

                ORDER BY
                    c.Company,
                    c.Project_Type,
                    c.Rating DESC
                LIMIT 3;

                SET ct = ct + 1;

        END WHILE;


    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Code I used to setup test (note: you should be including this stuff when you post your question; most people around won't go this far to help you):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contact;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contact (
    id int,
    Contact_Title  varchar(40),
    Contact_First  varchar(40),
    Contact_Middle  varchar(40),
    Contact_Last  varchar(40),
    Lead_Referral_Source  varchar(40),
    Date_of_Initial_Contact  varchar(40),
    Title  varchar(40),
    Company  varchar(40),
    Industry varchar(40),
    Address varchar(40),
    Address_Street_1 varchar(40),
    Address_Street_2 varchar(40),
    Address_City varchar(40),
    Address_State varchar(40),
    Address_Zip varchar(40),
    Address_Country varchar(40),
    Phone varchar(40),
    Email varchar(40),
    Status varchar(40),
    Website varchar(40),
    LinkedIn_Profile varchar(40),
    Background_Info varchar(40),
    Sales_Rep int,
    Rating numeric(6,4),
    Project_Type varchar(40),
    Project_Description varchar(40),
    Proposal_Due_Date varchar(40),
    Budget varchar(40),
    Deliverables varchar(40)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
id int,
Name_Title varchar(40),
Name_First varchar(40),
Name_Middle varchar(40),
Name_Last varchar(40),
Email varchar(40),
Password varchar(40),
User_Roles varchar(40),
User_Status varchar(40)
);


INSERT INTO
    users
        (id, Name_First, Name_Last, Email)
    VALUES
        (1, 'Name_First_1', 'Name_Last_1', 'Email_1'),
        (2, 'Name_First_2', 'Name_Last_2', 'Email_2'),
        (3, 'Name_First_3', 'Name_Last_3', 'Email_3'),
        (4, 'Name_First_4', 'Name_Last_4', 'Email_4'),
        (5, 'Name_First_5', 'Name_Last_5', 'Email_5'),
        (6, 'Name_First_6', 'Name_Last_6', 'Email_6'),
        (7, 'Name_First_7', 'Name_Last_7', 'Email_7'),
        (8, 'Name_First_8', 'Name_Last_8', 'Email_8'),
        (9, 'Name_First_9', 'Name_Last_9', 'Email_9'),
        (10, 'Name_First_10', 'Name_Last_10', 'Email_10'),
        (11, 'Name_First_11', 'Name_Last_11', 'Email_11');



INSERT INTO 
    contact
        (id, Contact_First, Contact_Last, Sales_Rep, Rating, Project_Type, Company)
    VALUES
        (1, 'Contact_First_1', 'Contact_Last_1', 1, 10, 'Type_1', 'Company_1'),
        (2, 'Contact_First_2', 'Contact_Last_2', 2, 9.9, 'Type_1', 'Company_1'),
        (3, 'Contact_First_3', 'Contact_Last_3', 3, 9.8, 'Type_1', 'Company_1'),
        (4, 'Contact_First_4', 'Contact_Last_4', 4, 9.7, 'Type_1', 'Company_1'),
        (5, 'Contact_First_5', 'Contact_Last_5', 5, 9.6, 'Type_1', 'Company_1'),
        (6, 'Contact_First_6', 'Contact_Last_6', 6, 9.5, 'Type_2', 'Company_1'),
        (7, 'Contact_First_7', 'Contact_Last_7', 7, 9.4, 'Type_2', 'Company_1'),
        (8, 'Contact_First_8', 'Contact_Last_8', 8, 9.3, 'Type_2', 'Company_1'),
        (9, 'Contact_First_9', 'Contact_Last_9', 9, 9.2, 'Type_2', 'Company_1'),
        (10, 'Contact_First_10', 'Contact_Last_10', 10, 9.1, 'Type_2', 'Company_1'),
        (11, 'Contact_First_11', 'Contact_Last_11', 11, 9, 'Type_2', 'Company_1'),
        (12, 'Contact_First_12', 'Contact_Last_12', 1, 10, 'Type_1', 'Company_2'),
        (13, 'Contact_First_13', 'Contact_Last_13', 2, 9.9, 'Type_1', 'Company_2'),
        (14, 'Contact_First_14', 'Contact_Last_14', 3, 9.8, 'Type_1', 'Company_2'),
        (15, 'Contact_First_15', 'Contact_Last_15', 4, 9.7, 'Type_1', 'Company_2'),
        (16, 'Contact_First_16', 'Contact_Last_16', 5, 9.6, 'Type_2', 'Company_2'),
        (17, 'Contact_First_17', 'Contact_Last_17', 6, 9.5, 'Type_2', 'Company_2'),
        (18, 'Contact_First_18', 'Contact_Last_18', 7, 9.4, 'Type_2', 'Company_2'),
        (19, 'Contact_First_19', 'Contact_Last_19', 8, 9.3, 'Type_2', 'Company_2'),
        (20, 'Contact_First_20', 'Contact_Last_20', 9, 9.2, 'Type_2', 'Company_2'),
        (21, 'Contact_First_21', 'Contact_Last_21', 10, 9.1, 'Type_2', 'Company_2'),
        (22, 'Contact_First_22', 'Contact_Last_22', 11, 9, 'Type_2', 'Company_2'),
        (23, 'Contact_First_23', 'Contact_Last_23', 1, 10, 'Type_1', 'Company_3'),
        (24, 'Contact_First_24', 'Contact_Last_24', 2, 9.9, 'Type_1', 'Company_3'),
        (25, 'Contact_First_25', 'Contact_Last_25', 3, 9.8, 'Type_2', 'Company_3'),
        (26, 'Contact_First_26', 'Contact_Last_26', 4, 9.7, 'Type_2', 'Company_3'),
        (27, 'Contact_First_27', 'Contact_Last_27', 5, 9.6, 'Type_2', 'Company_3'),
        (28, 'Contact_First_28', 'Contact_Last_28', 6, 9.5, 'Type_2', 'Company_3'),
        (29, 'Contact_First_29', 'Contact_Last_29', 7, 9.4, 'Type_2', 'Company_3'),
        (30, 'Contact_First_30', 'Contact_Last_30', 8, 9.3, 'Type_2', 'Company_3');
```

If this solves your problem, please remember to mark as answered, so everyone will know you no longer need help (and so I'll get rewarded for the two hours I spent helping you :-). If this doesn't meet your needs, please describe in as much detail as possible how it differs from your desired results and I'll try to revise.

Comment: Oh your amazing! It worked great! Thanks so much spending all that time helping me <3 Would have never gotten that

Comment: It was an interesting question and I'm glad I could help! Thanks for marking as answer!